# Laravel 4 on production: 403 forbidden error on ajax call to update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, laravel

I have a laravel 4 app that works fine on just a regular save with laravel. "Regular save" meaning that I'm not using ajax to call a URL to save the data from the form but using laravel's route to the URL /revocable/users/page/1/update.

I'm getting a 403 forbidden error during only an ajax call to a url:
/revocable/users/page/1/update

It's failing here:

```
$.ajax({
    type: action,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/revocable/users/page/1/update',
    data: {
        'oSerializeArray':  [array]
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
    }
})
    .done( function( data, text, jqxhr ) {
        data.success;
        //data.iPersonsPK;
        window.location.replace(sUrlEdit);
    })
    .fail( function ( data, jqxhr ) {
        data.success;
    })
    .always( function ( data ) {
        data.success;
    })

return false;
```

I think it's my virtualhost setting of my apache httpd.conf. I didn't have a virtualhost file when I got the 403 error.

I tried creating a virtualhost file with this:

```
<Directory "/home/myultrat/public_html/secure/test/*">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/secure.myultratrust.com.errors
```

But the problem is the same. I read that it could be a cross site script error. But it's on the same domain. All this code works well on my local machine with WAMP. So I'm thinking it's a vhost config problem.

Oh, I have to mention that laravel app is in a sub-directory not in the "traditional" way placed in the root of a sub-domain.

How do I resolve this problem?

Much thanks and blessings<><,
Victor

**UPDATED**

Such a simple fix. I needed to update the relative URL.

Changing the URL submitted to the $.ajax from `'/revocable/users/page/1/update'` to `'/test/revocable/users/page/1/update'` fixed the issue. @prabhakaran8737 was partially correct on the URL path not being correct. But (as I mentioned in a comment of his answer), all this time, I thought the URL was relative to where the request was made (i.e. `'/test/revocable/users/page/1/update'`) but $.ajax sees the URL call as based from it's root domain. So I needed to modify the URL to be based off the root and change it accordingly (i.e. `'/test/revocable/users/page/1/update'`).

I tried using absolute URLs too but that didn't seem to work either. So a relative URL from the root was the answer. And the relative URL had to have the beginning `/` forward slash. I tried `./` and I tried without the forward slash too but those didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is in url: '/revocable/users/page/1/update',

Assume If your in the page http://localhost/something/
and using the relating url `revocable/users/page/1/update` then the ajax request would be probably http://localhost/something/revocable/users/page/1/update and if your in the page http://localhost/another/ then the request will be to

http://localhost/another/revocable/users/page/1/update

So you wont find the right page there to handle request.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I saw your profile msg from elance btw. I changed the URL in my $.ajax call to the full URL `http://secure.myultratrust.com/test/revocable/users/page/1/update`

but the problem is the same. I even tried `./revocable/users/page/1/update` but to no avail. The URL `/revocable/users/page/1/update` (without the full URL) works on my WAMP though so I think it's Apache. I get the $.ajax reponse 404 page not found which is Apache's reponse.

Comment: In the above ajax call you have not mentioned the type as `post`

Comment: Make sure in the form serialization csrf is attached.

Comment: It was `PUT` but I also changed it to `POST`. Yes, the _token is attached. But it's still not working. But why would it all work on my WAMP local server before any of the changes. I think the only factor that has changed is the production server and that 404 error is Apache's error. So I'm still thinking that it's an Apache problem (version 2.2 for the production).

Comment: You were on the right path regarding the URL reference http://localhost/something/revocable/users/page/1/update. But the URL cannot be an absolute path though. I tried it. (see my UPDATE above). I think my problem is that I thought though that the URL would be relative to where the page was requested from but it's not. The URL is relative to the root domain so with a sub-domain it works properly but when the app is within a sub-directory then the URL needs to include anything after the root domain. So,in my case, `'/test/revocable/users/page/1/update'` is the correct URL to pass to the $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]
Just a note, I thought I posted this before Prabhakaran's response. But this still gives further clarity I think for someone or myself to resolve this problem. I pray this gets resolved soon. :)

This is not an answer but may help to lead to one. :)

I got to a certain point of understanding. The form saves the data on a POST request when I click the "save" button. This POST URL is
http://secure.myultratrust.com/test/revocable/users/page/3/update

The Laravel route works and it saves the data.

However, when I save the data via the "save an continue" button which executes the `$.ajax` call but still to the same POST URL Apache all of a sudden complains of a `404 error` page not found.

The same files and Laravel app works on my WAMP which is using 2.4.

I have this in my WAMP local server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName l4-confide
    ServerAlias l4-confide
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\test\trunk\php\l4-confide\public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:\wamp\www\test\trunk\php\l4-confide\public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options All Includes Indexes
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But my production server uses Apache 2.2. What's the equivalent of "Require all granted"? I'm not sure if this will resolve the problem though. I'm wondering why Apache complains of a 404 error not found  in an `$.ajax` call only and not when submitting (i.e. saving) the form the "regular" way (i.e. POST via HTML).

Comment: A bit late now, but you should edit your question if you wish to add further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
var csrf = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(request) {
                return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf);
            }
        });
```

Set var csrf to your csrf variable. My site I store it globally in a meta

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I had this already in my code:
`$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});`
I tried your code but it's still not working. :(

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent to "Require all granted" in Apache 2.2 is:

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

Check Apache upgrading:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Also, there are a few differences in the .htaccess (2.2 vs 2.4) but I'm not sure if the issue is related with it.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thank you for those references. All the options in Apache config and .htaccess can be a bit overwhelming.